# Can Xamarin open or import an Xcode project

Tags: xcode, xamarin-studio

Currently a client wants me to handle an ios project with xcodes , i wanted to know if it was possible to open or import an xcode project in xamarin.

because a client wants me to debug their project , and i dont have a mac to open it , only windows dev tools

Comment: No. No it can't.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Xcode produces native iOS applications in Swift, whereas Xamarin uses C# as its language.  They are two completely different things.